# How to process and then redirect in Spray?

Tags: scala, spray

I would like to be able to receive and process request via spray routing which will trigger (after a very short internal processing) a redirect to another page. I need processing to occur before the redirect, so using `redirect("/")` is not enough.

The only way I discovered so far to do this is coding a complete route handler, but there must be an easier one that I can't seem to figure out...

```
path("download") {
  get { ctx ⇒
    downloadInitiator.scheduleBackgroundDownload()
    ctx.redirect("/", StatusCodes.Found)
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: to be clear, imagine that Spray server needs to do a very small, almost ridiculous processing (let's say sending a fire-and-forget message to Akka cluster after a person has POSTed a contact form) and then execute a redirect.

For example, a perfect solution would be if Spray would allow `redirect` call to receive some kind of lazy executable function (like it's now case with `complete`) instead of terminating statement.

Comment: You can use a Future: http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/future-directives/onComplete/

Comment: How do you know when `scheduleBackgroundDownload()` completes? Do you use a callback?

Comment: Do you use akka? If yes, you may send a message to an actor and that actor starts doing background download and when it finishes it sends a message to itself and upon receipt of that message, you complete the request with redirect.

Comment: @Dimitri: I am using akka there, so that call "scheduleInBackground" is effectively just doing small (~1ms) of processing before it dispatches a message to akka in background. I didn't want to instantiate a Future for that only, I assumed there is a way to make a "short processing" in synchronous manner before redirecting user.

Comment: @Nami: I added extra explanation in the comment directed to Dimitri: yes there is entire Akka thingy back there, but in this case I am talking about very simple, short processing and I wouldn't like to chain futures or instantiating an actor just to use the onComplete.

Comment: I assume you expect spray to support for all complete function accepting a function which executes it before completing the request. As Dmitry suggested, I will do this with futures and do my computation which returns me a future and andThen (or onComplete) execute the redirect or complete. However I prefer to not put any logic in my routing definition and just send a message to underlying actor system.